# I want to convert following text file foo.txt to HTML file with table with column heading as status,displayname,name line using PowerShell?

Tags: html, powershell

```
Status     Display_Name       Name

Stopped    AJRouter           AllJoyn Router Service              
Stopped    ALG                Application Layer Gateway Service   
Stopped    AppIDSvc           Application Identity                
Stopped    AppMgmt            Application Management              
Stopped    AppReadiness       App Readiness                       
Stopped    AppVClient         Microsoft App-V Client              
Stopped    AppXSvc            AppX Deployment Service (AppXSVC)   
Stopped    AxInstSV           ActiveX Installer (AxInstSV)        
Stopped    BDESVC             BitLocker Drive Encryption Service  
Stopped    BthHFSrv           Bluetooth Handsfree Service         
Stopped    bthserv            Bluetooth Support Service           
Stopped    cphs               Intel(R) Content Protection HECI Service
Stopped    CscService         Offline Files                       
Stopped    defragsvc          Optimize drives                     
Stopped    DeviceAssociationService Device Association Service
```

I can't convert it straight away to HTML from command as it is a file made as a result of numerous `for` loop activities.

Comment: I can't convert it straight-away to HTML from Command as it is a file made as a result of numerous for-loop activities. -siva

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. What have you tried so far (show your code), and what *particular* problem (in your code) do you need help with?

Comment: @siva Thilak, edit your question and provide more detail,thats help others to understand what you want.

Comment: @omid What he wants is pretty clear. It's effort that the question is lacking.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers you`re right,but may be he have code and not provided yet,my comment is for attention: if you have try/code,provide it to help us better understand your part of problem. but your comment is better than me.(sorry for my bad en)

Answer (score 0):

From your provided foo.txt (in the end it is an output of Get-Service) I would just use:

```
Get-Service | where {$_.Status -eq 'Stopped'} | ConvertTo-Html
```

But that depends on what your initial objective is.

Assuming that it is a Tab delimted Csv and not only a bunch of white space you could use:

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter "`t" -Path $PathToCSV | ConvertTo-Html
```

If it is only a bunch of white spaces I would go back into my code and create a correctly formatted CSV or prefered a Powershell object to work with instead of writing and reading Csv files.